# Why does isSensorAvailable return true when device has disabled biometics in react native (android)

Tags: android, react-native, android-biometric-prompt, react-native-keychain

Context:

When using the react-native-keychain package to getGenericPassword, you should first verify that the device's biometrics are available so that you don't cause errors.

To check if biometrics are available, we use react-native-biometrics isSensorAvailable() method, BUT it seems that if the user has failed biometrics too many times on android, thus DISABLING the biometric prompts (both for device unlock and for keychain access) the result still gives available === true

here's the code sample

```
async function getSupportedBiometry() {
    const biometry = new ReactNativeBiometrics();

    const { error, available, biometryType } = await biometry.isSensorAvailable();
    console.log('biometrics result', available, biometryType, error);

    let biometricType = await Keychain.getSupportedBiometryType();
    if (
      available &&
      (biometricType?.toLowerCase()?.includes('face') ||
        biometricType?.toLowerCase()?.includes('finger'))
    ) {
      const result = await Keychain.getGenericPassword({
          service: 'molo',
          authenticationPrompt: {
            title: 'Biometric Sign In',
            subtitle: 'Confirm biometrics to continue.',
          },
        });
.
.
.
```

the output of

`console.log('biometrics result', available, biometryType, error);`

is

`biometrics result: true Biometrics undefined`

react-native-keychain's     `let biometricType = await Keychain.getSupportedBiometryType();`
is returning `Fingerprint` as well

so I can't figure out how to prevent the getGenericPassword function from running, which freezes the app since it cannot actually do this...

Any help is very very much appreciated!